# android - getString causes error getting from strings.xml

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Im currently working on an app which has a RecyclerView for the Settings Menu. My objective is to use strings saved in strings.xml for the RecyclerView, because my app has localization;
In my case, i generate the RecyclerView with a list saved in the fragment, which needs strings from string.xml, however, trying to call strings from the xml dosnt work.

**How do you pass strings from string.xml as parameters? How can i pass im this scenario?**

**frgSettingsMain.kt**

```
class frgSettingsMain : Fragment() {
    val listsettings = listOf(
        //using @string/string here doesnt work!
        dataListIcons(@string/..., "Description of option", R.drawable.ic_outline_color_lens_24),
        dataListIcons(I WANT THE STRING HERE, "Description of option", R.drawable.ic_outline_dashboard_24),
        dataListIcons("Option", "Description of option", R.drawable.ic_outline_image_24),
        dataListIcons("Option", "Description of option", R.drawable.ic_outline_volume_up_24),
        dataListIcons("Option", "Description of option", R.drawable.ic_outline_library_music_24)
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        retainInstance = true
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settingsmain, container, false)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        rvSettingsMain.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            adapter = adapterSettingsMain(listsettings)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): frgSettingsMain = frgSettingsMain()
    }
}
```

**dataListIcons.kt**

```
data class dataListIcons (
    val stringTitle: String,
    val stringDescription: String,
    val imageIcon: Int
)
```

**adapterSettingsMain.kt**

```
package com.meltixdev.revomusicplayer

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_settingsicon.view.*

class adapterSettingsMain(
    var listsettings: List<dataListIcons>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<adapterSettingsMain.SettingsViewHolder>() {

    inner class SettingsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SettingsViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_settingsicon, parent, false)
        return SettingsViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listsettings.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SettingsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.apply {
            rvSettingsTitle.text = listsettings[position].stringTitle
            rvSettingsDescription.text = listsettings[position].stringDescription
            rvSettingsIcon.setImageResource(listsettings[position].imageIcon)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `getString(R.string.stringname)`

**Edit**
will make some changes to your code

```
data class dataListIcons (
    val stringTitle: Int,
    val stringDescription: Int,
    val imageIcon: Int
)
```

---

```
val listsettings = listOf(
    
    dataListIcons(R.string.title1, R.string.desription1,   
    R.drawable.ic_outline_color_lens_24),
    dataListIcons(R.string.title2, R.string.desription2, 
    R.drawable.ic_outline_dashboard_24),
    .........
)
```

---

in your adapter

```
holder.itemView.apply {
        rvSettingsTitle.text = this.context.getString(listsettings[position].stringTitle)
        rvSettingsDescription.text = this.context.getString(listsettings[position].stringDescription)
        rvSettingsIcon.setImageResource(listsettings[position].imageIcon)
    }
```

Comment: This sadly doesnt work. The logcat thorows:
```java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment frgSettingsMain{f0fe9da (4ad0f02e-1afd-45cf-9b30-427e37e6f33c)} not attached to a context.```

Comment: This doesnt work either :/
Throws error: ```Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected```
I tried using Android Studio suggestion and that causes either crash or compilation error throwing type mismatch. Weird that all of these errors comes up since in the constructor both of the values are String. Im adding the data class to the question code.

Comment: @Meltix You have to declare the String varaiable as non nullable.You declared it as String? thus this error came.You can write like this var variable:String

Comment: @Sana i tried following your suggestion, but sadly this throws the same error as before:
```java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment frgSettings{f1bd9b3} (0a749187-38b6-45d4-bf8b-ae43e750a9c7)} not attached to a context.```

Comment: Alright i will confirm you answer, but i managed to solve this in another way. I still used getString as you suggested, however i moved the list in the onViewCreated before the .apply and now everything works!

Comment: **this** (context value) helped! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can always pass the string resource ids.

something like below:

```
  fun getList(): List<Int> {
    return listOf(R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name)
}
```

and wherever you need to get the string from ids just call

```
context?.getString(getList()[position])
```