# android - How to replicate Android 10 Settings

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, preferencescreen

Im currently developing an app which has a Settings menu. My App uses a dark theme as default theme, and i need to change Title and Summary text color. I also want to use icons like the Android 10 Settings menu:

[image: Screenshot taken from Android 10 Settings]

**How can i replicate this menu and with what component?**
**Is PreferencesMenu a valuable component to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can use **RecyclerView** and adapt a designed row.Design the row with a **ImageView** and two **TextViews**.Design as you wish for Text colors.In adapter just pass text and **drawables** as android 10.
You can use SVG drawables.

Set color at layout like this,

```
android:textColor="@color/colorlightblue"
```

Comment: Before asking this question i actually tried working with a RecyclerView, however i couldnt solve a problem that i had, preventing me to use a recyclerview. You can see the problem here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63104247/android-passing-string-from-string-xml-as-a-parameter

Comment: This whole settings menu you can customize using a RecyclerView and also it is good to be dynamic.I will see your recylcerview issue too